# Webpack bundle process adds a unique keyword "s;h++)i=t" which blocks the JS file to load from our network

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle

I'm having a tough time finding the root cause of the conspicuous keyword which gets added into the bundle JS when I compile all the ES6 JS to ES5 using webpack.

Due to the keyword `s;h++)i=t` our network blocks the javascript file from loading on the browser. Is there any way to tackle this or identify where this keyword comes from as a code?

Please help me resolve this issue.

Here's the webpack config - [snipper.io/s/-LZEl5h22gT5HzBDFwdf](https://snipper.io/s/-LZEl5h22gT5HzBDFwdf)

Thanks with regards

Comment: Fix your network.

Comment: please just supply your config. i fixed a similar problem at work yesterday. the 'keyword' you've supplied is just minified code

Comment: @Bergi I wish I could do (it's at client side)
Joe, here's the config - https://snipper.io/s/-LZEl5h22gT5HzBDFwdf

Comment: @Burhan add it to the question

Comment: @JoeWarner Done thanks

Comment: "*identify where this keyword comes from as a code?*" - the source map should tell you

Comment: I'm not sure how the minifier works exactly, but I'll guess that it either shortens variable names to their first character (if possible without collisions) or simply names them alphabetically in order of occurrence. Once you know what the original names of `h`, `i`, `s`, `t` were, you can try to change those things.

Comment: @Bergi there are over 19999+ combination of words which has `h`, `i`, `s`, `t` :')
I can't imagine checking each word.
I'm not sure if it shortens the variable names to their first character.
Also, I've tried looking into source map but not helpful as I thought :(

Comment: I can only hope your client pays extra for hand-optimised filter-avoiding code.

Comment: The security bot filtered that. I wonder what type of filter method they are using.

Comment: Why `s;h++)i=t` is being blocked? Is it because of the bad word it implies? I think you should focus on removing this protection instead of fixing the variable names that an obfuscator gives...

Comment: @alex-rokabilis yes it's because of the bad word. I can't remove the protection as it's not in my control. The only thing I can think of is to identify where it comes from and try to fix it with some way.

Comment: if it is truly because the network doesn't allow bad words?? then id complain to network admins as you cant for certain say your code will work based on arbitrary code minification

Comment: Thanks, Joe, I'll talk to the client if they can take some action.